# I want to receive an image through props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I want to access image through props. Last two properties working through "props" but image not working.but if image added in function instead of props then image working.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

  function Card(props){
   return(
     <>
      <div className="cards">
      <div className="card">
       <img src={props.imgsrc}
         alt="Mypic" className="card_img"/>
         <div className="card_info">
          <span className="card_category">{props.title}</span>

             <h3 className="card_title">{props.sname}</h3>   
             </div>
    
      </div>
  </div>
 </>
);
 }

  ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <Card 
    img src="/image/german.jpg"
     title="lorium excepted"
     sname="unexcepted"/>
     </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me there's a space between img and src where you're passing the props.

```
 ReactDOM.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
     <Card 
      img src="/image/german.jpg"   <--- should be imgsrc="/image/german.jpg"
      title="lorium excepted"
      sname="unexcepted"/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
 document.getElementById('root')
 );
```